# Meaning of "semper de"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In Ørberg's "Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata" in capitulo XIX on p. 149 it says,

> "Propter amorem nocte vix dormiebam - semper de te cogitabam..."

"Because of love I could barely sleep at night", but what follows then? I cannot make out the meaning of "de" in this particular case. Does "semper de" mean something like "ever since"?

Answer (score 8):

After having read the sentence a few more times, I realised that "de" belongs to "cogitare". Cogitabam de te - I used to think of you. / I was thinking about you.

Comment: With the imperfect, more like "I was always thinking about you" or "I constantly kept thinking of you".

Answer (score 1):

*De te* is de+ablative, *de*  is topical complement, focuses on the topic.

For example, Caesar's *De Bello gallico*  means 'About the Gallic War', the Caesar's account of the war. Or Lucrezio's *De Rerum Natura*, 'About the Nature of Things'.

So, as said in the comments, the phrase, whith the imperfect,  means 'I was always thinking about you'.